# How do I set the font color?

Tags: ios

the code below is working to draw text onto an image but it is black, and i need to change the colour. any suggestions?

```
UIFont* font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:250];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
CGSize size = [WmarText sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
// Create a bitmap context into which the text will be rendered.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
// Render the text
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
[WmarText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) withAttributes:attributes];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the Color in the attributes variable? Like this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

I think this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Add NSForegroundColorAttributeName with [UIColor whiteColor] to the attributes dictionary. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004903-SW2

Answer (score 0):

Add that:

```
NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]
```

into your attributes